# Twitter Bootstrap button-group as text input add-on isn't so nice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I've tried:

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
    <input type="text" />
        <div class="add-on btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dir="ltr">http://</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dir="ltr">https://</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

but the group-button's `padding` and `margin` made it ugly! you can see it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/dUbt3/)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `add-on` from `class="add-on btn-group"`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dir="ltr">http://</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dir="ltr">https://</button>
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

:)

Comment: What's the different between this and the other answer?